# Overlap-add method in 3D (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, 3d, fft, sparse-matrix

I have a three dimensional input `x`, let's say a 100x100x100 matrix, and it is rather sparse, maybe one element in a hundred is non-zero. I also have a pre-computed kernel matrix `k`. The operation that I need to perform in Matlab is

```
y = ifftn(k.*fftn(x));
```

How could this potentially be sped up? I was thinking about the overlap-add method implemeneted as `fftfilt` in Matlab, but this is only available in 1D.

Comment: Hm. I suppose if your matrix and kernel are sparse, you should use a [sparse array](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29832-n-dimensional-sparse-arrays) data structure and directly use the convolution `convn` instead of the fourier transform. (As by the [Convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem))

Comment: What is the performance of conv? I think it scales as O(N^2) where N is the number of non-zero elements.

Comment: I don't know about the implementation's complexity and can't compare the speed as you are not very specific with your matrix and kernel.

Comment: the kernel is k = fftn(u), where u is a 3D-Gaussian density profile, much smaller than the overall box size. Hence, k is also a Gaussian, meaning that it has non-zero values clustered mostly around small wavenumbers, and essentially zero for big wavenumbers

Comment: I'd give the 3D sparse `convn` approach a try. Trying to do kernel density estimation? You might also be able to use [this](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~ihler/code/kde.html).

Comment: I'm trying to boost a molecular dynamics program. Will try your suggestion!